# Issues with Multi-lingual website data caching - Python - Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, server-side, multilingual

**Question:**

What are the most efficient approaches to multi-lingual data caching on a web server, given that clients want the same base set of data but in their locale format. So 1000 data items max to be cached and then rendered on demand in specific locale format.

**My current approach is as follows:**

I have a multilingual python Google App Engine project. The multi-lingual part uses Babel and various language .po and .mo files for translation. This is all fine and dandy. Issues, start to arise when considering caching of data. For example, let's say I have 1000 product listings that I want clients to be able to access 100 at a time. I use memcache with a datastore backup entity if the memcache gets blasted. Again, all is fine and dandy, but not multilingual. Each product has to be mapped to match the key with the particular locale of any client, English, French, Turkish, whatever. The way I do it now is to map the products under a specific locale, say 'en_US', and render server side using jinja2 templates. Each bit of data that is multilingual specific is rendered using the locale settings for date, price formatting title etc. etc. in the 'en_US' format and placed into the datastore and memcache all nicely mapped out ready for rendering. However, I have an extra step to take for getting those multilingual data into the correct format for a clients locale, and that is by way of standard {{ }} translations and jinja2 filters, generally for stuff like price formatting and dates. Problem is this is slowing things up as this all has to be rendered on the server and then passed back to the client. The initial 100 products are always server side rendered, however, before caching I was rendering the rest client side from JSON data via ajax calls to the server. Now it's all server side rendering.

I don't want to get into a marathon discussion regarding server vs client side rendering, but I would appreciate any insights into how others have successfully handled multi-lingual caching

Comment: Question is way to broad.

Comment: Tim, I have to disagree. Read last paragraph again. That basically sums it up. I'm not asking for a particular solution, I have one. Doesn't mean I'm happy with it and was wondering how other people handle these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the individual product rendering in a particular language accounts for the majority (or at least a big chunk) of the rendering effort for the entire page.

You could cache server-side the rendered product results for a particular language, prior to assembling them in a complete results page and sending them to the client, using a 2D `product x language` lookup scheme.

You could also render individual product info **offline**, on a task queue, whenever products are added/modified, and store/cache them on the server ahead of time. Maybe just for the most heavily used languages?

This way you avoid individual product rendering on the critical path - in response to the client requests, at the expense of added memcache/storage.

You just need to:

- split your rendering in 2 stages (individual product info and complete results page assembly)
- add logic for cleanup/update of the stored/cached rendered product info when products add/change/delete ops occur
- (maybe) add logic for on-demand product info rendering when pre-rendered info is not yet available when the client request comes in (if not acceptable to simply not display the info)

You *might* want to check if it's preferable to cache/store the rendered product info compressed (html compresses well) - balancing memcache/storage costs vs instance runtime costs vs response time performance (I have yet to do such experiment).

Comment: Hi, Dan, yes spot on, the page is a product page, which is paged in lots of 100 items. I have considered offline rendering and will look at it further. I currently have code that handles any updates or deletes for stuff in cache using taskqueues. I was also considering on demand - so when a client sees the latest products I deliver the first 100 and then render in a task the next 100 and so on. This might be the best approach, at this time. I am going to experiment a little and see how it pans out.